# MPI hosts file, specify port number

Tags: mpi

I have a few nodes on the network connected to a router with port forwarding to talk to each of them individually. Is there some mechanism to specify the ip addresses of the nodes along with the appropriate port number in the hosts file that mpirun can use?

Comment: Which MPI implementation (MPICH, Open MPI, etc.)? The semantics of the hostfile are specific to the implementation.

Comment: This is with Open MPI.